# How to create an external address (New Meta mask address) in solidity which i can call later and withdraw funds

Tags: solidity, blockchain

I have a task in solidity where i have to create let say 10 new external addresses and transfer funds to these addresses. and then later withdraw funds from there addresses using the same contract. so question have two main parts.
**1) How to create new external addresses in solidity?
2) How to withdraw funds later from those addresses?**

Answer (score 0):

Every address from 0x000...01 to 0xFFF..FF "exist" already, so your question doesn't really make sense. I think what you want to do is to deploy a simple contract that would receive and  allow you to withdraw ETH at 10 different addresses from another smart contract. In that case, look up the factory pattern ( https://betterprogramming.pub/learn-solidity-the-factory-pattern-75d11c3e7d29 )

Comment: but i donot have privat ekey of all addresses, i donot want a contract i want an external address(address with private key), i should have its private key and should be able to use it later when i want to withdraw funds from that address. all this should be done inside the contract only.

Comment: Well, that's not something you can do with solidity. Ethersjs, web3js and probably every other web3 library in other programming languages have methods that lets you do that, though

Answer (score 0):

In solidity you can not create wallet account but you can create simple smart contract as many as you need. Using a factory contract you can deploy other contract and distribute eth to those contract. The issue is that you need to use proper coding so that your factory contract can send funds from those contract to wallet address. Eg. your simple smart contract code be as simple as this.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: None

pragma solidity 0.8.7;

import './IERC20.sol';

Contract SimpleContract {
    
    address public owner;

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    receive() payable external {}
            
    function withdrawEth(address to, uint256 amount) external onlyOwner {
        (bool success, ) = payable(address).call{value: amount}();
        require(success); 
    }
        
    function withdrawERC20(address tokenAddress, address to, uint256 amount) external onlyOwner {
        IERC20(tokenAddress).transfer(to, amount);
    }
    
}
```